# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already saw several questions with a similar question but can not resolve this problem.

Error that I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (large-file.js:103)
```

Line 103 is this:

```
instance.toResolve(pkt.ctrl.params.url);
```

**Code:**

```
this.xhr.onload = function() {
let pkt;
alert(this.response);
      try {
        pkt = JSON.parse(this.response, jsonParseHelper);
      } catch (err) {
        instance._tinode.logger("ERROR: Invalid server response in LargeFileHelper", this.response);
        pkt = {
          ctrl: {
            code: this.status,
            text: this.statusText
          }
        };
      }

  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
    if (instance.toResolve) {
      instance.toResolve(pkt.ctrl.params.url);
    }
    if (instance.onSuccess) {
      instance.onSuccess(pkt.ctrl);
    }
```

...

```
function jsonParseHelper(key, val) {
  // Convert string timestamps with optional milliseconds to Date
  // 2015-09-02T01:45:43[.123]Z
  if (key === 'ts' && typeof val === 'string' &&
    val.length >= 20 && val.length <= 24) {
    let date = new Date(val);
    if (date) {
      return date;
    }
  } else if (key === 'acs' && typeof val === 'object') {
    return new AccessMode(val);
  }
  return val;
};
```

I included `alert(pkt);` for testing purposes and it shows:

[image]

JSON.parse does not work for some reason:

```
[17:39:41.547] ERROR: Invalid server response in LargeFileHelper {"ctrl":{"id":"69834","params":{"url":"/v0/file/s/zYrwWlHrrGI.bin"},"code":200,"text":"ok","ts":"2021-06-09T17:39:45.719Z"}}
```

The response is valid. Could be a problem that this response comes from Nginx proxy and response headers contain the following?

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

If I can (alert) response received from the server,it's a string but Nginx proxy automatically adds Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: `pkt` is a string, not an object. Otherwise, it would show as `[Object object]` in the alert dialog. Pro tip : you should really try `console.log(pkt)` instead of `alert` :)

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Where is `jsonParseHelper` specified? I think that could also be the cause for the error

Comment: I added jsonParseHelper to the question.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L51r8vmp/1/) for a working example. Try to isolate the issue, e.g. find out what exactly the input is that causes the issue, then directly assign it instead of making the XHR request (and dropping the XHR code), etc. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further info

Comment: Also I'd suggest to log the `err` object and see if it is really what you would expect